# No covariance results in Matrixnormal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, covariance, matrix-normal

Let's say we estimate the matrix $\beta_{N\times N}$ which is the coefficient matrix of a simple multiple linear regression $Y=X\beta+\epsilon$ where $Y, X, \epsilon\in R^{T\times N}$. If we assume:
$$cov(b_{ij},b_{ik})=0\quad\forall i\neq j \neq k$$ can we claim that $\beta\sim MN$, where $MN$ is the matrixnormal distribution?

Comment: That claim has no chance of being true unless, at a minimum, you assume $\epsilon$ has a special form of multivariate Normal distribution and you perform the estimate using ordinary least squares.  Out of curiosity, in what sense is this a "simple" multiple linear regression?  Perhaps the meaning of that will include some of the missing assumptions you need.

Comment: If the noise is multivariate normal and iid then would this hold? I am still not able to figure out the sufficient conditions for the coefficient matrix to be $MN$. @whuber